# How to get external folder

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I download pdf file downloaded from the Internet. To public folder download/.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/", fileName);
```

If I try

```
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(StudyMaterialActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file), format);
```

Path to file directed to data folder of application.

In provider_path xml file `<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>`

How I send file path with intent to PDF viewer?

**UPDATED**: Now I open external viewer `ntent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), format);
startActivity(intent);`
My project has targetAPI 23 and I want to change to last API - 25. If I change targetAPI to 25 app crash while Uri.fromFile(file)

Comment: `How I send file path with intent to PDF viewer?` ??? Strange question. You already put an uri for the file in an intent to open any available viewer.

Comment: `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS `. No good. You should use `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)..... `.

Comment: Please tell the value of `getUriForFile(....).getPath()`.

Comment: Method ...getPath() response /external_files/Download/Test_-_unit_5.pdf

Comment: If I change-up targetAPI to 25 I can´t use intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), format).

Comment: You are not reaction to all things i said. And you also did not tell why you could not use setDataAndType. Are you serious? Do you want help? Then give better info and tell more.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot write full information about my code (problem)

Comment: You are so unclear with all those questions which are still the same. And now it looks that all works in 23. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, if targetAPI set to 23 app is ok. I try update to tagetAPI 25 and app is crashing. So I stay on API 23 :) Thanks all for answers